Binance futures testnet data differs from read binance futures data
I am new to binance api and now I am using binance futures testnet. I’ve noticed that the data that testnet shows differs from the real futures data.
Testnet data:

Real data:

Additionally testnet data looks kind off even and steady, does anyone know the reason?
Thanks!

Testnets are intentionally separate from mainnets.
Even though they usually run the same architecture (and some new features are deployed on testnets first), testnets usually do not reflect any data from mainnets.

One of the purposes of a public testnet is to provide environment to test your application against the architecture (in case of Binance trading platform, that can be e.g. API responses).
But it's not a simulation of a production environment in terms of data.
If you want to submit test trades against the live data, you can make use of their test endpoints: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#test-order-trade
